# Updating row on QTableWidget cause segmentation fault

Tags: qt4, qtablewidget

I have QTableWidget connected with `totale()` slot and [itemChanged(QTableWidgetItem *)](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtablewidget.html) signal, in my table I am tracking user change on column 3 and 5.

```
void Store::totale(QTableWidgetItem *x)
{
    int row = x->row();
    float sum = 0;
    float ttl = 0;
    QTableWidgetItem *item = NULL;
    if (ui->storeTab->currentIndex() == 1)
    {
        if(x->column() == 5)
        {
            item = new QTableWidgetItem;
            sum = ui->itemsTableWidget->item(row, 3)->text().toFloat() * x->data(0).toFloat();
            item->setText(QString::number(sum, 'f', 2));
            ui->itemsTableWidget->setItem(x->row(), 6, item);
            sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < ui->itemsTableWidget->rowCount(); ++i)
            {
                ttl += ui->itemsTableWidget->item(i, 5)->text().toFloat();
                sum += ui->itemsTableWidget->item(i, 6)->text().toFloat();
            }
            ui->totaleBill0->setText(QString::number(sum, 'f', 2));
            ui->ttlBill0->setText(QString::number(ttl, 'f', 2));
        }
        else if(x->column() == 3)
        {
            item = new QTableWidgetItem;
            sum = x->data(Qt::DisplayRole).toFloat() * ui->itemsTableWidget->item(row, 5)->text().toFloat();
            item->setText(QString::number(sum, 'f', 2));
            ui->itemsTableWidget->setItem(x->row(), 6, item);
            sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < ui->itemsTableWidget->rowCount(); ++i)
            {
                ttl += ui->itemsTableWidget->item(i, 5)->text().toFloat();
                sum += ui->itemsTableWidget->item(i, 6)->text().toFloat();
            }
            ui->totaleBill0->setText(QString::number(sum, 'f', 2));
            ui->ttlBill0->setText(QString::number(ttl, 'f', 2));
        }
    }
}
```

My problem if I make change on column 5, it works fine, but when I made change on column 3 I get segmentation fault.

Comment: use debugger to catch the error

Comment: @ KamilKlimek Too bad that my skills is still in development. I found that when i add a new row, a textChanged signal emited, so when I perform multiplication, the columns(in my case the cells of the new row) of QTableWidget are still not filled, if I access to data cell, I get segmentation fault, but unfortunately I still can't find a solution to that.

Comment: Remember to check if pointer returned by ui->itemsTableWidget->item(int, int) is not null. You're probably dereferencing a null pointer

Answer (score 1):

Try to turn off cellChanged(int,int) signal while adding new rows (disconnect and connect it). In that way you will not have situation to read from cells that are not filled

Comment: Yes, I had the same issue and i was consuming itemChanged() SIGNAL for the table. after populating table and viewing the table, if i try to insert some row, application was crashing. I've disconnected before inserting, and after all set items are done, i connect the signal again. now it works. thanks :)